# Magento - Exclude Gift Cards From Discount Codes

Tags: magento, checkout, enterprise, discount

This seems like it would be pretty straightforward but I can't seem to find anything on this...

I am setting up a Gift Card product in Magento Enterprise V 1.14 and have one issue. In the checkout, users can still apply discount codes to the Gift Card product (which is obviously not something you would want). I know I can go back through all of our codes and add an exclusion to the gift card category, but we have a lot of codes and I don't want to have to edit 100 codes with this rule. Also don't want a new code to be created without this exception and have someone end up taking 20% off of a gift card.

Is there another way to do this other than editing the exceptions for 100 codes and every code made from here on out? I feel like it would be easy and actually a default setting for gift cards.

Thanks for the help, interwebs!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just go into the coupon rules and exclude the gift card item sku under Actions. Worked like a charm.

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
If ALL  of these conditions are FALSE :
    SKU  is  GIFTCARD
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is down-voted because you said you wanted to do all of your items at once. You should give a reason for the down-vote however, as this is a decent, general answer.